# Modify OS Security Module Configuration on SELinux vs AppArmor

Tags: centos, mysql, selinux, apparmor

Just some pretext, I am fairly new to this and I'm still learning how SELinux works.

I am trying to Modify OS security module configurations, but the instructions given to me were for Ubuntu and AppArmor.

I am trying to change a few lines in the equivalent of the following file:

```
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

However, I need to do this in SELinux and I am having trouble finding this file. Where can I access this file or something similar with SELinux? I am using CentOS 7.

Comment: What is the change that you're trying to mimic?

Comment: I need to modify MySQL DB data path.

Answer (score 0):

AppArmor and SELinux work differently.
When AppArmor works on tunables and profiles, such as /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld, SELinux works on contexts and booleans. If you want to make some change for the file /usr/sbin/mysqld, you can check it's context by listing it with "-Z" option:
`ls -Z /usr/sbin/mysqld`

Then you can set appropriate boolean for the context, but it really depends on what exactly you want to do. If you want to learn more on how SELinux works, there's a good explanatory video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WOKRaM-HI4